# Is it safe to always instantiate UI in AppDelegate's application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) method?

Tags: ios, swift

Since I'm not using Storyboard-based layout on my iOS project, I am wondering about the following issue:

AppDelegate's method:

application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)

Is calling not only on user-initiated app launch, but on occasions, the push notifications, VOIP push notifiactions, location-based interactions can call this method from the background as well, and since I am initiating a window and an initial view controller there, like so

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window!.rootViewController = MainRouter().viewController()
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

I am wondering is my application in risk of termination by the OS if, for example, push notifications, or location-based self-launching call application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) when app is in terminated state? Since it is documented for Voip push notifications that is is highly recommended to avoid complex CPU usage, heavy UI loading, API calling for cases when app self-launches from terminated state?

Answer (score 1):

The delegate method

```
application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)
```

is always called **once**.

The mentioned services can cause to **launch** the app – if it's currently not running – and the affected service is indicated in the `LaunchOptionsKey`.

If the app is running but not in the foreground Push Notifications, Location Services etc. call other methods.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the effort. But, maybe my question isn't clear enough, I know that the method is fired once on app launch, but the question is, will the device (OS) provide runtime if my app is launched from terminated state by other events that are not user-initiated? For example, if VoiP push notification arrives, am I allowed to init UI? Since the user will not see it anyways, but maybe OS will detect a "power virus" and terminate my app before my app dones some quick backgound task?